Why enable JMX in Java Tomcat don't work?
I followed the tutorial https://geekflare.com/enable-jmx-tomcat-to-monitor-administer/.
I just add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=my public ip
If write ps –ef | grep jmx, i have
debian@xxx:/usr/share/tomcat10/bin$ ps -ef |grep jmx tomcat      1363       1 98 18:32 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat10/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=public ip -classpath /usr/share/tomcat10/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat10/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat10 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat10 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

But netstat –anlp | grep 9000 return nothing, and Zabbix is correctly configured (it work with Zabbix agent on port 10050). I try to turn off the firewall on Zabix server.
You have an idea ?
Thanks
EDIT :
I making progress
debian@vps-6f6c0318:~$ sudo netstat -anlp |grep 9000
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1363/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9000                ::1:60976               TIME_WAIT   -   

            

I managed to connect with jconsole.
But, i always "Unknown status" in Zabbix ...
